# Kendo numeric textbox currency format with prefix

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am trying to format a number in a Kendo numeric textbox in USD, but I would like to prepend the country code to the resultant string (US$123.45) to allow it to be distinguishable from other dollar-based currencies.

Kendo's .format function provides me with the output that I am after:

```
kendo.format("US{0:c2}", 123.45) // US$123.45
```

But the .toString function does not behave the same way:

```
kendo.toString(123.45, "US{0:c2}", "en-US") // US{123.45:c2}
```

Which is the same output I am getting in the widget when trying to pass "US{0:c2}" as the value for the format property.

Struggling to find any other way to do this after looking through kendo's docs, SO posts, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% if this lines up with what you need due to lack of context in your question and no sample code for your numeric textbox config, but I'm going to give it a try.

You can use a custom number format on your numeric textbox to achieve what you want like so:

```
$("#numerictextbox").kendoNumericTextBox({
    format: "US$0.00",
});
```

[Here is an example in a Kendo Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/aRUqeWIz)

Comment: Apologies, my numeric textbox is very basic and so I thought questioning number formatting specifically was enough context.
That suggestion has worked, but commas are omitted ("US$5000.00" vs. the desired "US$5,000.00").
Changing the format to "US$#,###.00" has given me the desired behaviour.
Thanks for your help!